# Using SFINAE to detect if overloaded free-standing function exists at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03

Here is my [unsuccessful attempt](http://rextester.com/JEDAV76554) at detecting whether a free-standing function `void set( T& , void (T::*Func)( const char* ) , const char* str )` exists for any class/struct `T`, in C++98/03.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Foo;
struct Bar;
struct Fuu;

void set( Foo& , void (Foo::*Func)( const char* ) , const char* str )
{
}

void set( Bar& , void (Bar::*Func)( const char* ) , const char* str )
{
}

template <typename T>
class setter_is_implemented
{
public: 
    typedef void (*SetterFunction)( T& , void (T::*)( const char* ) , const char* );

    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;

    template <typename C> static one test( C c, SetterFunction = c ) ;
    template <typename C> static two test(...);    

public:
    enum { value = sizeof( test<T>(&set)) == sizeof(one) };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << setter_is_implemented<Foo>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << setter_is_implemented<Bar>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << setter_is_implemented<Fuu>::value << std::endl;
}
```

GCC error message

```
Test.cpp:24:66: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
     template <typename C> static one test( C c, SetterFunction = c ) ;
                                                                  ^
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class setter_is_implemented<Foo>’:
Test.cpp:33:44:   required from here
Test.cpp:28:35: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
     enum { value = sizeof( test<T>(&set)) == sizeof(one) };
                                   ^
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class setter_is_implemented<Bar>’:
Test.cpp:34:44:   required from here
Test.cpp:28:35: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
Test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class setter_is_implemented<Fuu>’:
Test.cpp:35:44:   required from here
Test.cpp:28:35: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, taking the address of an overloaded function happens before overload resolution, so SFINAE cannot work in that way. This is also harder because your function returns void (otherwise, one would just check the size of the result ). My C++03 metaprogramming is rusty, but this should work (<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/010b665f17bd8703)</kbd>):

```
namespace setter_is_implemented_detail {
  struct dummy1 { char c[2]; };
  typedef char dummy2;

  dummy2 operator,(dummy1, dummy1);

  template<typename T> dummy1 set(T const&,...);

  template <typename T>
  struct impl
  {
    typedef void (T::*FT)( const char* );
    static T& x;

    enum { value = sizeof( set(x,static_cast<FT>(0),static_cast<const char*>(0)), dummy1() ) != sizeof(dummy2) };
  };
}

template <typename T>
struct setter_is_implemented: setter_is_implemented_detail::impl<T>{};
```

note a few things:

- `set()` needs to be found by ADL here (not a big deal, as far as I can tell from your problem description)(*)
- the comma operator trick(**) is needed due to the void return type; in gcc, you *can* take the `sizeof(void)`, so the code can be simplified there
- this won't work for non object types (due to the `static T&`). It can be made to work though, if you need so...

---

(*) Note that this cannot work for every possible `set()` overload; this is true for any sfinae, even in c++17, `set()` must always be sfinae-friendly in order to work.

If you need to match sfinae-friendly set() overloads exactly, it's still possible to do it, but it's more complex; I'd do it in two phases: first you use the above code to find possible candidates, then you check the function pointer conversion, somewhat like you do in your original code ..

(**) This trick works because if `set()` has `void` return type (and hence exists) the comma is always interpreted as the built-in comma operator (see *c++03[3.9.1/9]: "An expression of type void shall be used only as an expression statement (6.2), as an operand of a comma expression[...]"*) resulting in the right-most expression. Otherwise, the dummy set and comma operator are used.

Comment: Simply brilliant!!! ....

Just a few questions. Why `sizeof( dummy1(), set(x,0,0), dummy1() )` instead of just `sizeof(set(x,0,0), dummy1() )`?

Comment: ... Also I can't quite see how `operator,` gets around `sizeof(void)`

Comment: @Olumide, yes the sizeof can be simplified, that was a copy-past remnant of a previous try, edited

Comment: @olumide, regarding the 'operator,', if set 'returns' void, the comma is always interpreted as the built-in comma, resulting in the last expression to be evaluated (=dummy1()); if set is not found, the dummy set is selected along with the overloaded comma operator, resulting in dummy2...

Comment: "if set 'returns' void, the comma is always interpreted as the built-in comma"

Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: @olumide from the c++03 standard: [3.9.1/9]: "An expression of type void shall be used only as an expression statement (6.2), as an operand of a comma expression[...]"; and you cannot write an overload taking 'void'

Comment: Simply amazing ... Gonna mark your answer now. Suggest you add that reference to your answer for clarity/posterity.

Comment: There is one tiny issue though. I'm getting false positives for incorrect function prototypes e.g. `void set( Fuu& , const char* , const char* )`

Comment: you need to constrain it more; anyway, note that it cannot work for every possible set(); this is true for any sfinae, even in c++17, set() must be sfinae-friendly in order to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160633/discussion-between-olumide-and-massimiliano-janes).